# Google Maps API Suddenly Not working On Public Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Google Maps API v3 suddenly stopped working on my live server; however still works on my localhost. I haven't changed anything, so I assume it doesn't have to do with my code.

Also note that my production and development servers are the same.

I'm running **Ruby 1.93** and **Rails 3.2.13** using **Refinery**. I created a location extension for refinery; which is just a locations model, and I use **Rails Geocoder** to geocode the address for Google Maps Api.

I Have a search field that uses the maps api for near locations.
It stopped working a couple of days ago, and then started working again last night.

I just randomly tried again after I pushed some unrelated stuff to git. It was still working this morning.

Then I was working on some unrelated things did a push, and just tried it again and it's not working again.

No matter what, it still works on my localhost and I'm stuck. Does anyone have a clue, or does anyone else have any issues currently with **Google Maps API v3**

**EDIT: New Issue Working on Resolution: Follow Up Here** [Setting up Rails Geocoder with Personal API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524165/setting-up-rails-geocoder-with-personal-api-key)

Comment: Perhaps you reached your geocoding limit?

Comment: I geocode myself with Geocoder.

Comment: Ah yes, reading is good.

Comment: and geocoder uses? googlemaps by default

Comment: OKay, I've updated billing and generated a new browser key - updated site and still not working. But of course it works on localhost. So... I am confused of what this can be.

Comment: Are you aware there's various 404 errors after a search ? Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://pastapomodoro.com/fonts/stylesheet.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://pastapomodoro.com/stylesheets/add2home.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://pastapomodoro.com/javascripts/jquery.backstretch.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

For most applications, it is recommended to do any geocoding on the client side. This not only helps you avoid the usage limit, which is based on IP address, but it keeps some stress off your server.

If geocoding on your application happens when people enter an address through a search field, this is a great option, and you can still send any info you need back to your server through an ajax call.

For further strategies, see here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

Comment: Hi cole, thanks for the suggestions. That makes a lot of sense. This site is used in production and I will eventually go this route; however, I've updated my billing generated a new Browser key, and replaced the obsolete key, which is set to expire tomorrow, with the new key, pushed and even restarted rails app and it's still not working. Do you have any clues as to why this would suddenly stop working besides reaching limit?

Comment: At what point do you see it's not working? Markers aren't showing up? Map not showing up? Error messages? Etc.?

Comment: If the usage limit was the problem, the status code on the geocoding response should be OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, and if that is the case you may have to wait 24 hours, or contact someone from google billing to clarify.

Comment: When I open your site I see a bunch of errors pop up in the console, i.e. `GET http://pastapomodoro.com/assets/jquery-backstrech.js 404 (Not Found)`. I'm not sure if that is the issue, but maybe some of your resources aren't being properly loaded in production.

Comment: Hey cole, yea I have got a few buggy things going on with js, but this isn't the issue. It's been going on for a while, and I am refactoring everything now that I have a better grasp on a lot of things. And actually I'm using the same in development that I am using in production. It's always worked, and I haven't made any major changes.

Comment: The first thing I would do is find out if it's the usage limit problem by inspecting the geocode response. If it is, maybe you have to wait 24 hours or contact google billing to clarify, but at least you know where the problem is.

Comment: Nice, did you find it was the usage limit? There might be a cooldown period for them to lift it.

Comment: No that's what's weird. I'm digging more now. I'll share my conclusions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I figured out what's going on. Here is a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524165/setting-up-rails-geocoder-with-personal-api-key

Answer (score 0):

I sadly went with Microsoft's Bing service. Google Premier account is 10,000 bucks. I was just bragging how I was Microsoft free for almost 2 years. Sad Day. Meanwhile I'll work on making geocoding client side. Thanks everyone.